# How to merge/mix/overlay multiple videos, with time-shifts?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

**How to merge/mix/overlay multiple videos, with time-shifts?**

Example: I'd like to take:

- 4 seconds of `1.mp4` and it should start at 0'10" in the output video
- 8 seconds of `2.mp4` and it should start at 0'11" in the output video
- 16 seconds of `3.mp4` and it should start at 0'12" in the output video

They will be overlaying/overlapping themselves; example: if `1.mp4` is 400x400, `2.mp4` is 200x200, and `3.mp4` is 100x100 pixels, then at 0'12" we will see the 3 videos at the same time, overlapping each other.

```
ffmpeg -t 4 -i 1.mp4
       -t 8 -i 2.mp4
       -t 16 -i 3.mp4
       -filter_complex [0][1][2]overlay[out]
       -map [out]
       out.mp4 -y
```

I see there is a `overlay` [`t` parameter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-overlay-1), but how to specify a different starting-timestamp for each video?

It seems we cannot use `-itsoffset` for multiple sources at the same time: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1349

Comment: Search `[ffmpeg] is:answer overlay setpts`

Comment: Thank you @llogan. I read them carefully, and I have now a working code, but it seems unnecessarily complex, do you think you know how to simplify this code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66256414/mixing-various-audio-and-video-sources-into-a-single-video? Thanks in advance.